# Format text inside R code chunk

Tags: r, markdown, rstudio, knitr

I am making some slides inside Rstudio following instructions here: 
http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/beamer_presentation_format.html

How do I define text size, colors, and "flow" following numbers into two columns?

````
```{r,results='asis', echo=FALSE}
rd <- sample(x=1e6:1e7, size = 10, replace = FALSE)
cat(rd, sep = "\n")

```
````

Output is either HTML (ioslides) or PDF (Beamer)

**Update:**

Currently the code above will only give something like the following

```
6683209
1268680
8412827
9688104
6958695
9655315
3255629
8754025
3775265
2810182
```

I can't do anything to change text size, color or put them into a table. The output of R codechunk is just plain text. Maybe it is possible to put them in a table indeed, as mentioned at this post:

http://tex.aspcode.net/view/635399273629833626273734/dynamically-format-labelscolumns-of-a-latex-table-generated-in-rknitrxtable

But I don't know about text size and color.

**Update 2:**

The idea weaving native HTML code to R output is very useful. I haven't thought of that. This however only works if I want to output HTML. For PDF output, I have to weave the native Latex code with R output. For example, the code following works using "knitr PDF" output:

````
```{r,results='asis', echo=FALSE}
cat("\\textcolor{blue}{") 
rd <- sample(x=1e6:1e7, size = 10, replace = FALSE) 
for (n in rd) {
cat(paste0(n, '\\newline \n')) } 
cat("}")
```
````

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are using results='asis', hence, you can simply use `print()` and formatting markup. If you want your text to be red, simply do:

````
```{r,results='asis', echo=FALSE}
print("<div class='red2'>")
rd <- sample(x=1e6:1e7, size = 10, replace = FALSE)
cat(rd, sep = "\n")
print("</div>")
```
````

Hope it helps.

Comment: `print` may not work but `cat` does. I updated my question to reflex your answer. Thanks and I decide to award the bounty to you.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds as if you want the output to be either PDF or HTML. 
One possibility is the `xtable` package. It produces tables either in PDF or HTML format. There's no (output-independent) way to specify colour, however. Here's an example.

```
xt <- xtable(data.frame(a=1:10))
print(xt, type="html")
print(xt) # Latex default
```

Another option is the `pandoc.table` function from the `pander` package. You need the `pandoc` binary installed. If you have RStudio, you have this already. The function spits out some markdown which then can be converted to HTML or PDF by `pandoc`.

Here's how you could use this from RStudio. Create an RMarkdown document like this:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "You"
date: "20 November 2014"
output: html_document
---


```{r,  results='asis'}
library(pander)
tmp <- data.frame(a=1:10,b=1:10)
pandoc.table(tmp)
```
````

When you click "knit HTML", it will spit out a nice HTML document. If you change output to pdf_document, it will spit out a nice PDF. You can edit the options to change output - e.g.

```
pandoc.table(tmp, emphasize.strong.rows=c(2,4,6,8,10))
```

and this will work both in PDF or HTML. (Still no options to change colour though. Homework task: fix `pandoc.table` to allow arbitrary colours.)

Under the hood, `knitr` is writing markdown, and `pandoc` is converting the markdown to whatever you like.

Comment: Your answer also introduces the idea, of mixing native target document code (i.e. HTML/Latex). Thanks for re-introducing `xtable` package to me. But as you said the part of formatting colors is not clear.