# R markdown: levels of factor on different lines

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am using R markdown to create student feedback sheets, based on survey data we collect from their assessors. Input has 10 questions imported in *.csv format. Example data:

```
question <- as.factor(c(NA, NA, "response 1.", "response 2.", NA, "response 3."))
```

At present I am running `r levels(question)[-1]` in my `*.rmd` file which gives me this output (with ", " as separators):

```
response 1., response 2., response 3.
```

Note that there are always some NAs so the [-1] is just to remove the NA level of the factor.

What I want is to create output with each response on a new line:

```
response 1. 

response 2.

response 3.
```

I can do this on single forms by specifying the levels on each level i.e.

```
r levels(question)[2]

r levels(question)[3]

r levels(question)[4]
```

However for each question there are variable numbers of non-NA responses (1 up to 4) so I need a solution which does not explicitly have to know how many there will be. i.e. same code will give desired formatting for both q1 and q2:

```
q1 <- as.factor(c(NA, NA, "response 1.", NA, NA, "response 2.")

q2 <- as.factor(c(NA, NA, "response 1.", "response 2.", "response 3.", "response 4.")
```

Usually I would address this with a for-loop but Markdown doesn't read code the same way as R console. Have tried `as.character` rather than `as.factor` but didn't seem to help; calling `levels(question[-1])` seemed most straighforward method to remove `NA`s.

Thanks!

Comment: Ya, I'm also very unclear at what the specific question is here.

Comment: `cat(paste0(question, "  \n"))` perhaps?

Comment: or `cat(paste0(levels(question), "  \n"))` for the levels

Comment: @tospig `cat(paste0(levels(question), " \n"))` generates the desired output but puts it into the Rmarkdown console rather than printing it in place in the document...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use the new line markdown operator `"  \n"` to put each response on a new line in your document.

````
```{r}
question <- as.factor(c(NA, NA, "response 1", "response 2", NA, "response 3"))
```

`r paste0(levels(question), "  \n", collapse="")`
````

I had a [similar question to this here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29581239/4002530)

Note that I used `cat` in my comment so you could see it printed in the console. In the markdown document the rendering is taken care of so you don't need the `cat`

Comment: worth adding this similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66109880/how-to-print-a-list-as-bullet-items-in-word-using-rmarkdown) which adds a bullet point to each level