# How to print a list as bullet items in Word using Rmarkdown

Tags: r, ms-word, r-markdown, knitr, officer

I have a list that looks like

[1] "SR7" "SW 38"  "NW 35"  "NW 34"

[5] "NW 31" "NW 27 " "SW 24 " "SW 22"

[9] "I-95 SB" "I-95 NB"

I want to print them as bulleted items in word, using R-markdown. It looks like below

1. SR7
2. SW 38
3. NW 35
4. NW 34
5. NW 31
6. NW 27
7. SW 24
8. SW 22
9. I-95 SB
10. I-95 NB

Can anyone show how to do that ?

Comment: Bulleted list, or numbered list?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add `*` before each list item:

````
---
title: "Bullet List Example"
author: "M.Viking"
date: "2/8/2021"
output: word_document
---

```{r bulletlist, results='asis'}
mylist <- c("a", "b", "c")
cat(paste("*", mylist), sep = "\n")
```
````

> ```
> • a
> • b
> • c
> ```

Above is an unnumbered list. To generate an ordered numbered list, replace `*` with `1.`.

````
```{r numberedlist, results='asis'}
mylist <- c("a", "b", "c")
cat(paste("1.", mylist), sep = "\n")
```
````

> ```
>  1. a
>  2. b
>  3. c
> ```

Comment: For those new to Rmarkdown, `results='asis'` is important to getting this output.