# How can I print an R macro in Markdown in colour?

Tags: r, markdown, knitr, r-markdown, sweave

I have a print statement in `R` as a macro in `Markdown`

````
```{r chunk_name, echo=FALSE}
if ( any(so.results$Duration <0.0))
{print("there are non-positive  durations")
} else
{print("all  durations are fine!")}
```
````

and I want to generate a PDF, not an XML! How can I print `"all  durations are fine!"` in colour for example green or red?

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26819258/format-text-inside-r-code-chunk) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29067541/rmarkdown-how-to-change-the-font-color) seem to have the answer. Change to `results='asis'` and then `print("\textcolor{red}{all  durations are fine!}")` should work

Comment: No unfortunately it dose not work, I guess it would work if I would be able to change the colour in R print-statement

Comment: Hi, can you explain what do you mean "it doesnt work". This prints red text when i render the pdf ... have i misunderstood? Or more generally, you could define  new print function statement, that takes a colour argument ... `colprint <- function(x, col="red") print(paste0("\textcolor{", col, "}{", x, "}"))`

Comment: @user20650 thank you that works naturally if I change ```{r, results='asis'}  then I get not just a colour but the whole code too! Is it any possibility to get just the text in colour without to get the code

Comment: @user20650 every thing is now fine, I used the following code:    ` ```{r, results='asis', echo=FALSE}
if ( any(so.results$Duration <0.0))
{cat("\n")
 print("\textcolor{blue}{print("there are non-positive  durations}")
} else
{cat("\n")
 print("\textcolor{red}{print("all  durations are fine!}")}
``` `  and that works proper. Thanks a lot, would you give your comment as an answer please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29067541/rmarkdown-how-to-change-the-font-color) and [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26819258/format-text-inside-r-code-chunk) and the hints given by [User](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2250190/user20650) I wrote the following:

````
 ```{r, results='asis', echo=FALSE}
 if ( any(so.results$Duration <0.0)) 
  {cat("\n") print("\textcolor{blue}
   {print("there are non-positive durations}") 
} else 
{cat("\n") print("\textcolor{red}{print("all durations are fine!}")}
 ```
````

which solves the problem.