# Split code into several syntactically invalid chunks in R Knitr

Tags: r, markdown, knitr

Is it possible to get a nonformated markdown text inside a code chunk? My goal is to diplay a description inside a `for` cycle. In the example below, such operation leads to splitting the code into two syntactically invalid chunks:

````
I am using for cycle here
```{r results='hide'}
for(i in 1:5){
  foo()
```

There is a lot of interesting stuff inside
```{r results='hide'}
  bar()
}
```
````

which would ideally generate:

I am using for cycle here

```
for(i in 1:5){
  foo()
```

There is a lot of interesting stuff inside

```
  bar()
}
```

Comment: Spoof it. Put your syntactically complete code chunk with `echo = F`, then break up your code however you want with `eval = F`.

Comment: @Gregor : I want my code to be evaluated.

Comment: Right, but you can only evaluate syntactically valid code. So the first one that you **do** evaluate has all your code and is syntactically valid, but has `echo = F` so it won't be displayed. Then you can display the code however you want, in as many chunks as you want, with `eval = F`. And it won't matter if you break up a for loop across chunks because no evaluation means no syntax error.

Comment: ok, now I get it. Well, this will perhaps work, but I need to have the code there twice. But thanks anyway.

Comment: Related (but definitely not duplicate), could that method work? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26819258/format-text-inside-r-code-chunk

Comment: Do you mean something like the feature described in the section [Advanced usage of the echo option](http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/output/)? Not sure if I get the question because you write that you want to split a chunk into pieces, but then you show different codes (and not code that is a subset of other code).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following advice from the comment by **user2706569**, you can define the code chunk once with a name and evaluate it. Then you can reuse the code chunk, but only echo the lines you want, and without evaluation.

Drawn from [Yihui's examples](http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/output/)...

````
The plots from the original evaluation are 
shown, but the code is not echoed here. (To 
omit all of the outputs, check out the 
chunk options such as `include=FALSE`.)

```{r mychunk, echo=FALSE}
## 'ugly' code that I do not want to show
par(mar = c(4, 4, 0.1, 0.1), cex.lab = 0.95, cex.axis = 0.9,
    mgp = c(2, 0.7, 0), tcl = -0.3)
plot(mtcars[, 1:2])
plot(mtcars[, 4:5])

```

Now describe the code as you wish without evaluation.

Here's the first and second lines from the original chunk.

```{r mychunk, echo=1:2, eval=FALSE}
```

Here's the third line.

```{r mychunk, echo=3, eval=FALSE}
```

Here's the fourth line.

```{r mychunk, echo=4, eval=FALSE}
```

Here's the fifth line.

```{r mychunk, echo=5, eval=FALSE}
```
````