# knitr: How to format text outputted by code chunk in Rmarkdown?

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

````
```{r}
library(knitr)
text <- c("apple", "orange")
for(i in text){
  cat(paste("I have an", i))
}
```
````

In Rmarkdown, is there a way to format text outputted by a code chunk using the `cat` command? I know that I can format the font outside of the code chunk (e.g. `##Header` to make it bigger and bolded, etc). But what about the text "inside" a code chunk?

Comment: Does [this question help at all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26819258/format-text-inside-r-code-chunk)?

Comment: @Anonymouscoward thanks, it helps, but I tried doing `cat("\centering")`  but I'm getting `\c` is an unrecognized escape as an error message

Comment: You want "\\centering" (double backslash), but this is only going to work for LaTeX output.  If you want HTML output it's completely different.  You need to say which output format.